# Proving $f^{-1}(Y\setminus F)=X\setminus f^{-1}(F)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I need to prove the following:

$f^{-1}(Y\setminus F)=X\setminus f^{-1}(F)$
where $f : X \rightarrow Y$

I tried it out as follows, but am uncertain whether or not I managed to prove it correctly

$f^{-1}(Y\setminus F)=f^{-1}(Y\cap R\setminus F)$

$=f^{-1}(Y)\cap f^{-1}(R\setminus F)$

$=X\cap f^{-1}(R\setminus F)$

$=X\setminus f^{-1}(F)$

Can someone kindly confirm whether this is a correct proof?

Comment: Your proof is OK. For $A$ minus $B$ use 'A \setminus B'.

Comment: Thanks, I am only just getting started to use the MathJax software